# creating an ARCH series from white noise in R

Tags: r

Suppose I generate a white noise of 100 observations with mean zero and a constant variance using code `vt <- rnorm(100,0,1)`
now I want to create an ARCH series of the form e(t) = v(t)*sqrt(1 + e(t-1)), with the initial condition that e(0)= 0. What code can help me create this series.
I was using `et <- vt*sqrt(1 + lag(et))` but due to obvious reasons this didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance,

Sahil Talwar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
v <- rnorm(100)

# ARCH(1) parameters
Xi    <- 1
alpha <- 1

y <- vector()
y[1] <- 0
for(i in 2:length(v)) {
  y[i] <- sqrt(Xi + alpha*y[i-1]^2) * v[i]
}

plot(x=1:length(y), y=y, col="red", type="l") #ARCH
lines(x=1:length(v), y=v, col="blue") # iid white noise
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved my problem!